# Mongoose: how to catch MongoError caused by async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I'm trying to push too large data into `mongoDb` I'm getting this error: `MongoError: document is larger than the maximum size 16777216`

I know, it is normal, but I can not catch this error, and my `node.js` process exits.

Can you tell me, how to catch this error?

**example.js: can not catch the error, `node` process exits**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', {name: Object});


setTimeout(function () {
    var kitty = new Cat({
        name: {
            value: 'Zildjian',
            data: (new Array(16 * 1024 * 1024)).join("x")
        }
    });

    kitty.save(function (err) {
        if (err) // ...
            console.log('meow');
    });

}, 1000);
```

I've tried to wrap my code into a `try...catch` but that doesn't caught the error either.

Comment: @downvoter, pls tell me why is the downwote. I could learn from it, if you'd tell me what is the problem with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `setTimeout` is async and put callback outside call stack is provide to error rise to top of stack. So don't' use the `setTimeout`, or you can add an additional error handler:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  if (err.name==='MongoError') {
    mongoose.connection.emit('error', err);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(0);
  }
});

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', {name: Object});


setTimeout(function () {
    var kitty = new Cat({
        name: {
            value: 'Zildjian',
            data: (new Array(16 * 1024 * 1024)).join("x")
        }
    });

    kitty.save(function (err) {
        if (err) // ...
            console.log('meow');
    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why can I catch other type of errors? If I change the type of `name` to `String` in the definition `mongoose.model('Cat', {name: String})` and remove the huge data from it: `data:{}`, I'll get a `[ValidationError: Cat validation failed]` and it is caught. Why validationError can be caught but  the maxSize is not?

Comment: Because Mongoose differently handles errors: validation error is handled by the callback function (see `mongoose/lib/error/validation.js`), but an error with the size of the document emerges through `throw` (see `mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js`).

Comment: It is a good answer, but the problem itself was in mongodb, which is fixed here: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/06fd4db11d7d1b312136b63cd70ba4ce3a720023

Comment: Complementing the @stdob-- answer ...
I think that we should catch errors using reference to MongoError "class" (construction function).

```const MongoError = require('mongodb-core').MongoError
/* [...] */
if (err instanceof MongoError) {
    /* do something */
}
```
Only in this way we're sure that we're catching proper error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait for the connection to be up. Wait for the "open" event:

```
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  // Your code goes here                    
});
```

As specified here: https://gist.github.com/mongolab-org/9959376

Comment: Did you try this? I've tried and didn't work either.

Comment: Really sorry, just answered from memory. Fixed my answer,

Comment: It was clear what you said, but it still didn't solve the problem. Did you try it?

Comment: Not with your specific code, but this is how you wait for the mongoose connection to be ready and it is working in my code. But it's interesting why you can't catch it inside a timeout, only outside...

Comment: My problem is not the connection but the error handling. I'm connected to mongo, just can not catch the error message. And still can not catch it, even if I move my code into the connection callback.

Comment: Yes, I know. I thought the not waiting for the connection was an obvoius suspect introducing race conditions and what not. But there's a new and better answer for you by stdob--